# Использование diff linux

Tags: linux

Собственно есть 2 больших текстовых файла, в каждом примерно по 5-10kk строк, нужно их сравнить(строки), и записать результат в 2 файла, где в первом будут дубликаты(строки которые есть и в первом и втором файле) и уникальные, те которые есть только во втором файле, справится ли с такой задачей diff и как будет выглядеть команда для консоли, спасибо.

Comment: Kk в смысле «миллионов»?

Comment: да миллионов строк

Comment: `diff` не ищет дубликаты. Если у вас сортировки нет, то `diff` может вам создать файлы в 10-20kk строк на выходе.

Comment: Пара вопросов. 1) все строки в каждом из файлов  уникальны? 2) файлы уже отсортированы?

Comment: строки уникальны, но не отсортированы

Comment: @Monolith  imho в таком случае diff не годится. По крайней мере понять к какой категории относятся некоторые строки в его выводе будет не просто. / Наверное проще всего для решения задачи будет отсортировать файлы и сделать свою простую программу для вывода результатов в 2 файла за один проход исходных. / (кстати, если хотите, чтобы человек, которому вы отвечаете в комментарии его увидел, добавляйте в свой коммент @nick)

Answer (score 2):

Похоже, что описанная задача как раз для команды comm. Если ее запустить и передать два файла, то она распечатает в три столбика - уникальные для первого файла, уникальные для второго и строки, которые есть в двух файлах. А вот "регулировка вывода" работает немного необычно. `-1` подавляет первый столбец, `-2` - второй и `-3` - дубликаты.